# Can i pass values to a model method from rspec?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I have a model method as follows.

```
 def method_a

     get_result_params(val1,val2)

 end
```

Here i want to pass val1,val2 from rspec file. Is it possible? If yes please let me know..

Comment: Why do you want to change the arguments - what are you trying to do?

Comment: Do create a helper method.. bring that method inside the `*_spec.rb` file... and use it.. Rspec supports `helper` method creations..

Comment: i am getting invalid val1 and val2. so i want to pass correct values to check that method

Comment: @ArupRakshit Please explain in a answer

Comment: This is enough. https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/helper-methods/define-helper-methods-in-a-module

Comment: @poojaagarwal why are `val1` and `val2` invalid? Where do these variables come from?

Comment: @Stefan they were coming from inside the class.

Comment: @poojaagarwal could you add `val1` and `val2` to your example code above, starting with a `class` definition? I don't understand how this fits together.

Comment: @Stefan i am getting 0,0 for val1 and val2

Comment: @poojaagarwal please edit your question and add the relevant details.

Comment: my question is very simple. Just i am asking can we pass val1 and val2 from rspec file.?

Comment: @poojaagarwal - you think you've given us all the information, but you haven't. Your question is simple, but lacking enough information for us to help you. Can you please edit your question, and add in the *spec* that you are using - the spec that is giving you errors. Also please add in the *error* that you are seeing when you run that spec. Thirdly - tell us *what you are trying to achieve* with this spec. Until you give us *really* all the information, we really can't help you (your question is too vague to answer in its current form).

Answer (score 0):

Allow the model to accept the parameters

```
def method_a(val1, val2)
  get_result_params(val1,val2)
end
```

call it from the spec by the model

```
Model.method_a(3,4)
```